# Complement of a regular expression

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, regular-expressions

**Question.**

> Write a regular expression for the languages:
>
> 1. all words in $\{a,b,c\}^{*}$ in which $a$ instance is followed by a sequence of at least two $c's$
> 2. The complement language of $1$

**Attempt.**

> 1. $\,\,\,\,r=(b+c+accc^* )^*$

But I'm not sure how to write regular expression of the complement.

Comment: The $c^*$ in your answer is unnecessary. Just $(b + c+acc)^*$ is good enough. Your answer works, too, though.

Comment: For question $2.$, if you can't see it directly, I suggest the following **hint.** you can create an automata that recognizes $\mathcal L (r)$, and you (must) know how to construct an automata that recognizes $\overline{\mathcal L (r)}$. After this, you can extract a regular expression $s$ such that $\mathcal L(s) = \overline{\mathcal L(r)}.$

Comment: @roro the automata must be dfa?

Comment: The automata that recognizes $\mathcal L(r)$ must be a dfa, because otherwise you can't construct an automata that recognizes $\overline{\mathcal L(r)}$. But keep in mind that if you don't construct a dfa for $\mathcal L(r)$ directly you can always transform it into a dfa...

Comment: @roro I got $r=(b+c)^* (a+ac)(a+b) (a+b+c)^*$ but it doesn't feel so right to me.

Comment: Actually feels right to me (I have no idea what the answer is supposed to be, just tried some words). If you want, answer your own question with all you did and I can give it a look!